# Can't load font woff

Tags: debugging, .htaccess

I have relatively simple issue but I can't fix it myself.

My log is full warning with same message:

```
page not found    
http://mywebsite.com/sites/all/themes/bigwig/font/entypo-icon-font.woff
```

I have looked around and most of suggestion is about .htaccess and I tried to add such block (but no luck).

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I have tried to access other files in folder via browser and everything worked except the one with *.woff

```
http://mywebsite.com/sites/all/themes/bigwig/font/*
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

It seems somewhere you have something referencing that file. First place I’d look is on the theme folder.

If you have access to a Linux or Mac machine, you can `cd` into the folder and run,

```
grep -rn ‘entypo-icon-font.woff’ . 2>/dev/null
```

This will tell you if there’s a file that has a mention to that file.

To fix, you can either remove the reference to that file or see if you’re able to find the file and add it to the path on the url.